Spring Security auth sevrer permitAll not working as expected ( Closed )
I am using Spring authorization server here, i have two controller one is /user/** and the other is /client/**, now what i want is /user/** can be accesses publicly and /client/** can only access by authenticated user, i have used two filter chains one is for auth-server that redirect all request starting /client/** to /login , and other is that handle redirect to /login page, this is my configurations :
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Order(1)
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain authServerFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter) throws Exception {
    
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
    
        http.exceptionHandling(ex -> ex.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                        new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                   // redirect all unautheticated /client/** to login
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/client/**")
    
             ))
            .oauth2ResourceServer(rs -> rs.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter)));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Order(2)
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        req -> req.requestMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .build();
    }

}

Here is my user endpoint that i am trying to access
@Controller
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/user/")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello from User Controller";
    }
}

what i have expected is to get output, but , i am getting redirected to /login page
I have tried setting logging.level.org.springframework.security=debug, and this gives :
2024-09-22T14:23:35.456+05:30  INFO 131685 --- [spring-oauth2-auth-server] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-09-22T14:23:35.457+05:30  INFO 131685 --- [spring-oauth2-auth-server] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-09-22T14:23:35.459+05:30  INFO 131685 --- [spring-oauth2-auth-server] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2024-09-22T14:23:35.492+05:30 DEBUG 131685 --- [spring-oauth2-auth-server] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /user
2024-09-22T14:23:35.508+05:30 DEBUG 131685 --- [spring-oauth2-auth-server] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-09-22T14:23:35.512+05:30 DEBUG 131685 --- [spring-oauth2-auth-server] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /user
2024-09-22T14:23:35.548+05:30 DEBUG 131685 --- [spring-oauth2-auth-server] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2024-09-22T14:23:35.549+05:30 DEBUG 131685 --- [spring-oauth2-auth-server] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-09-22T14:23:35.553+05:30 DEBUG 131685 --- [spring-oauth2-auth-server] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2024-09-22T14:23:35.580+05:30 DEBUG 131685 --- [spring-oauth2-auth-server] [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2024-09-22T14:23:35.810+05:30 DEBUG 131685 --- [spring-oauth2-auth-server] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /favicon.ico
2024-09-22T14:23:35.811+05:30 DEBUG 131685 --- [spring-oauth2-auth-server] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-09-22T14:23:35.812+05:30 DEBUG 131685 --- [spring-oauth2-auth-server] [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2024-09-22T14:23:35.825+05:30 DEBUG 131685 --- [spring-oauth2-auth-server] [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login


requestMatchers("/user/**").permitAll() doesnt match /user. It would only match sub resources of /user/ such as /user/account for example. Add requestMatchers("/user").permitAll() for /user specifically if you need it

thanks for answer,but  i think /user/** will work for /user also, i am in spring security 6 , and also i have found solution it was happening because of / in @RequestMapping after user/

@kushparsaniya if you found a solution, please add it as an Answer for future readers.

Ok i have found solution it is happening because of @RequestMapping("/user/") trailing slash after user / so i have updated it to @RequestMapping("/user") and it works fine.
